# Swift ObjectMapper mapping an array with multiple types of values - numbers and complex objects mixed

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I have this JSON object that I want to parse using Swift [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        0,
        {
            "data": {
                "username": "myuser"
            },
            "expires": 300,
            "timeout": 300,
            "ubus_rpc_session": "some_value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't figure out how to properly parsed the inner array with mixed content, specifically this part:

```
[ 0, { /* ... */ } ]
```

I have tried to solve it in various ways, but haven't been able to find a working solution. I suspect `StaticMappable` might work, and I have used it for other Polymorphic parsing, but never when one of the array items is a number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable` but even in Codable you need a custom init method to handle the heterogenous array.

Comment: Even with Codable you need some expectation of what will be in the array. The only way I know of handling it is, for each element, to try to decode it as a bunch of different types until something works. The result totally depends on which types you try and in what order.

Comment: Or you can just google "swift ubus_rpc_session" or check the [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+ubus_rpc_session) here on stackoverflow and see if any of them are helpful

Comment: Thank you all for commenting, let me reply in order

Comment: @vadian thank you but I don't have the possibility to use anything but ObjectMapper at this point

Comment: @JoakimDanielson None of those answers cover ObjectMapper as far as I can tell. But thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the only way to map this array, using `ObjectMapper`, is in `[Any]`:

```
class Result: Mappable {
    var id: Int?
    var jsonrpc: String?
    var result: [Any]?
    
    required init?(map: Map) {}
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        jsonrpc <- map["jsonrpc"]
        result <- map["result"]
    }
}
```

That way, for this particular json response, the first element of the array will be of type `Int` and the second will be of type `[String: Any]`.

Of course, this includes the type casting procedure whenever you are trying to access an element of this array. (which is just bad)